# Defining a Function

Tags: functions, finance

I've been reading about functions in *Mathematica* and playing with this for hours, but I'm clearly missing something. The following code correctly calculates "fail", the number of failed scenarios.

I want to convert the code between the dashes to a function of the variable "spend" that returns the value of fail as the value of that function, in other words `f[spend]:=fail`. Can someone please show me how to do this while defining the code as a `Module`?

Thanks.

```
n = 10000; (* Number of samples to generate  *)
years = 30; (* Number  of years in each simulated scenario *)
mu = .056; (* Average portfolio rate of return *)
sigma = .11; (* Portfolio standard deviation *)
portfolio = 1000000; (* Initial portfolio value *)

withdrawal = .042; (* Annual spending percentage of initial portfolio value *)
returns = Table[1, {n}]; (* one scenario of market returns *)
spend = withdrawal*portfolio; 

(* --------------------------- *)

fail = 0;

For[k = 1, k <= n, k++,
 returns = RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[mu, sigma], {years}];
 x = portfolio;

 For[i = 1, i <= years, i++,
  x = returns[[i]]*x - spend
  ];
 fail = fail + If[x <= 0, 1, 0];
 ]

(* --------------------------- *)

Print["Failed: ", fail]

Print["Percent failed: ", N[fail/n, 3]]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 3):

You just need `fail` as the last expression in the module, so that it gets returned:

```
f[spend_] := Module[{fail = 0, returns, x},
  For[k = 1, k <= n, k++, 
   returns = RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[mu, sigma], {years}];
   x = portfolio;
   For[i = 1, i <= years, i++, x = returns[[i]]*x - spend];
   fail = fail + If[x <= 0, 1, 0];];
  fail]
```

A faster approach will be to generate all the returns at once and use `Fold` to do the iterative calculation and `Total[UnitStep[...]]` to count the negative results:

```
f[spend_] := Total[UnitStep[-Fold[Times[##] - spend &, portfolio, #] & /@ 
    RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[mu, sigma], {n, years}]]]
```

Comment: Thanks! Still cant see what I was doing wrong, but I think I was messing up the syntax around that last "fail" in the function. Your alternative is elegant. I'll need to study that for a while. Out of curiosity, should mu, sigma and years also be localized in the first approach? (I'm switching to your function, regardless.)